# Highlighting invalid fields using "!" after validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a red exclamation mark next to textbox which are not filled in.

I'd rather want that text box background went red (or a red border appeared around the text box) as I think that looks better.

Can anyone give me a piece of code that will achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with what you tried so far? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Which one do you want, red “!”, or red background, or red border? After deciding, show what you have tried and how it fails. You also need to decide whether validation means HTML validation (with attributes like `required`), or CSS validation, or both, as this affects the implementation.

Comment: i want a red "!" with a red border and I want a javascript validation.

Comment: @VishalChugh Hope the updated answer helps...

Answer (score 0):

You'd want a function to validate the form, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Here's an example I made:

```
function validateForm(){
    var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName("input") //get all the inputs
    var valid = true;
    for(var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++){ //for each inputs
        if(inputs[i].type == "submit" || inputs[i].type == "button") //ignore buttons
            continue;
        if(inputs[i].value == ""){ //if input is empty
           inputs[i].className = "invalid"; // set class to "invalid"
            valid = false
        }else //if inputs is not empty
            inputs[i].className = ""; //remove class
    }
    return valid
}
```

it attaches a class "invalid" to all the empty inputs. This is better [semantically](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames) then just changing the background color. Then in the css you can have:

```
input.invalid{ background-color:#dd1111; }
```

You need to attach that to a form's `onsubmit` event so it would be able to prevent submition (by returning false) e.g:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form")
for(var i=0, len=forms.length; i<len; i++){
    forms[i].onsubmit = validateForm
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/CbxcM/

Comment: @freefaller lol. I don't see why everyone hates them so much.

Comment: Then you haven't read the website I've linked to.  Your choice whether to use them or not, absolutely nothing stopping you... mine is not to use them and I've giving the reason why

Comment: Thanx fr d ans @TastySpaceApple. Just tell me the method to add '!' at the end of boxes that aren't filled.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the textboxes in a container element such as `<div>`, you can use css pseudo element [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to display the `!` as shown below:

```js
function validate(){
 var txts  = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
 for(var i=0;i<txts.length;i++){
  if(!txts[i].value)
   txts[i].parentNode.classList.add('invalid');
  else
    txts[i].parentNode.classList.remove('invalid');
 }
}
```

```css
.invalid input{
  border-color:red;
}
.invalid::after{
  content:"!";
  font-weight:bolder;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div><input type='text' /></div>
<div><input type='text' /></div>
<div><input type='text' /></div>
<input type='button' value="Validate" onclick="validate()" />
```

---

Reference:

- [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)
- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)